# Use google maps in multiple fragments - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity which creates a new fragment containing SupportMapFragment, using FragmentTransaction. In this new fragment I am creating the google maps object in onMapReady method, and also retrieving the user location.

In the activity I will need to create a new fragment, that also contains a SupportMapFragment, but with different layout than the previous one. The flow will look like this:

Activity -> MapFragment1 -> get google maps and location
         -> MapFragment2 -> get google maps and location

I will need something like this:
Activity -> get google maps and location -> MapFragment1
                                         -> MapFragment2

Is there a way to actually create the google maps and have the user location in the activity, and then somehow pass it too all the fragments derived from the activity?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Are you saying your activity will have two Google maps?

Comment: I want to have the same google maps for both fragments.